# Is it possible to create an inline try without a catch like shown

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I have this case where I want to run code that may have an error but I don't need to catch it.

If the response is not valid JSON then the result should be 0:

I'd like to  use this code:

```
var overallProgress = try {JSON.parse(text)} ? 0;
```

Is it possible to the above?

Or something like this:

```
var overallProgress = try { JSON.parse(text)} catch(error) { 0 }; 
var overallProgress = try { JSON.parse(text)} catch(error) { overallProgress = 0 };
```

There are errors using the code above.

I found this related post below but no answer.

[Is try {} without catch {} possible in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764107/is-try-without-catch-possible-in-javascript)

For anyone whose eyes I've hurt:

```
var overallProgress = 0; 
try { overallProgress = JSON.parse(text).overallProgress } 
catch(error) { overallProgress = 0 };
```

Comment: `try` blocks aren't assignable.

Comment: "*I don't need to catch it*" - but you do

Comment: @Bergi ackshually, i could define progress as zero beforehand and update the value only if

Comment: @1.21gigawatts and then still you need to catch the exception (to ignore it, by *not* updating the progress variable).

Comment: @Bergi this makes me think a `JSON.verifyValidJSONString(mystring)` would be useful

Comment: @Bergi the reason for the JSON.validate() method would be so you could avoid the try catch block conundrum

Comment: @1.21gigawatts You mean `const overallProgress = JSON.validate(text) ? JSON.parse(text) : 0`? That would have to parse the JSON string twice.

Comment: @Bergi you presented another use case. the use of trinary support. my json is about 200 characters. so 1/100000000 of a second to parse. that's ok

Comment: If not using it for a conditional, what did you propose `validate` and `verifyValidJSONstring` methods for?

Comment: @Bergi I misunderstood. That's exactly what I would use it for or the predefine the value and update the value only if JSON is valid case.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no. But you can use an IIFE:

```
const overallProgress = (() => { try { return JSON.parse(text) } catch { return 0 } })();
```

I'd still format it as multiple lines though:

```
const overallProgress = (() => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(text);
  } catch {
    return 0;
  }
})();
```

Apart from being able to use `const`, it doesn't really have an advantage over simply using two assignments:

```
let overallProgress;
try {
  overallProgress = JSON.parse(text);
} catch {
  overallProgress = 0;
}
```

or even

```
let overallProgress = 0;
try {
  overallProgress = JSON.parse(text);
} catch {
  /* ignore: keep `overallProgress` value */
}
```